# Increasing union of $\sigma$-algebra generated by intersections of intervals

Tags: measure-theory

I am aware of the property that for a sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $(\mathcal{A}_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that $\mathcal{A}_i \subsetneqq \mathcal{A}_{i+1}$ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $\cup_{i\geq 1} \mathcal{A}_i $ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now, let $\Omega=(0,1]$ and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\mathcal{A_n}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the intersections of the set $(1-2^{-n},1]$. How to show that the union of $\mathcal{A_n}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Your particular sequence $\mathcal A_n$ doesn't satisfy $\mathcal A_n\subset \mathcal A_{n+1}$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you intend the $\cal A_n$ to satisfy $\cal A_n\subset A_{n+1}$? Defining the $\sigma$-algebra
$$
{\cal A_n}:=\sigma(\{(1-2^{-1},1], (1-2^{-2},1], \ldots, (1-2^{-n},1]\})
$$
will make an nested collection of $\cal A_n$. To show their union (write ${\cal A}:=\bigcup_n\cal A_n$) is not a $\sigma$-algebra, look at the (countable) collection of sets of the form $B_n:=(1-2^{-n},1]$. Then $B_n\in{\cal A_n}$ so each $B_n$ belongs to the union $\cal A$, but their intersection (namely, the singleton $\{1\}$) belongs to none of the $\cal A_n$.

Comment: Why do we considerate the intersection of the $B_n$? This is not a property of a $\sigma$-algebra. I do see that $\{1\}$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$, belongs to none of the $\mathcal{A}_n$'s, but how does this fulfill the counter-example?

Comment: The $B_n$ are a collection of sets that belong to $\cal A$ but their intersection does not.  This shows that $\cal A$ is not a sigma-algebra, because sigma algebras are closed under countable intersections.